# Sails.js : use i18n in my controller

Tags: node.js, view, controller, internationalization, sails.js

In my controller I want to send a message in my view like that :

```
res.status(400).view('memberRegisterView',{error : "error"});
```

And I want to translate this error in french and have "erreur".

I edited i18n.js :

```
locales: ['en', 'fr'],
defaultLocale: 'fr'
```

In my en.json :

```
"error":"error"
```

In my fr.json :

```
"error":"erreur"
```

How to use translation in my controller ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as the doc say http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Internationalization

```
req.__('error');
```

Or to force french :

```
sails.__({
  phrase: 'error',
  locale: 'fr'
});
```

Comment: sorry I did not see this part in the doc.

Comment: req.__ is not a function. What worked for me in controller was  req.i18n.__('message-key')

Answer (score 2):

@damien-marchand, @jaumard

Following helped me with i18n in sails:

```
<h1> <%= req.i18n.__('message-key') %> </h1>
```

as per the sails documentation https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/internationalization
following should have worked, but it didn't

```
<h1> <%= __('message-key') %> </h1>
```

Moreover,

```
sails.__('message-key')
```

works but it is not tied to the request's language.